# Fullcalendar Safari colors

Tags: colors, safari, fullcalendar

The events I display each day have many types, each type defined by a specific color.

When I have multiple events in a day, same color, the opacity of second, third, etc. color is reduced, step by step.

This is happening only on Safari. Somebody had this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't had that problem so far, can you show the .fullCalendar() method you're calling?